# Google map type load time and bundle

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an Android application where the usage of user's internet should be limited to small amount of bundles even if the user would be loading the map so often, and here comes the question,

**do all the Google map types available in Android load by consuming same internet or one type is heavier than the other one ?**

Meanwhile, do all use the same amount of bytes to load even if they are displaying the map in different types of view?

Comment: Seems like something you might be able to determine experimentally; I doubt there's official word on the bandwidth used by each display type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lite mode https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite.

Provides almost the same utilities than the fragment map but serves an static image instead.